# Smaller SpreadsheetML files through Excel 2007

Tags: xml, excel, language-agnostic

I have a SpreadsheetML file that I am generating server-side.  Such files are rather large, in contrast to Excel 2007 files, which make use of zip.  So, I am wondering if there is a simple way, **without use of automation**, to create an a zip file with that file inside...which Excel 2007 must know how to open.  I do know that Excel 2007 knows how to open xlsx files, but I believe xlsx files use OpenXML rather than SpreadsheetML.  However, I wonder if it is possible to embed a SpreadsheetML file into an xlsx file in a way that Excel 2007 will understand.

The answer to this question might be no.  I wish to avoid the use of 3rd party components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer **is** NO.

Answer (score 0):

You could always send the user a server-generated ZIP file with the SpreadsheetML file inside.  While Excel 2007 can't open it directly, the user can open it in their default archive program and open the contained SpreadsheetML in Excel. One more step for them, but beats waiting around for a verbose XML file to download.